# Pemission denied when I try to create a new file with a script

Tags: centos, bash, scripting

So, I have a bash script "get-data.sh that runs other two python scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

scripts=/root/scripts
datos=/root/zabbixdata
fecha=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")

sudo $scripts/filesystem.py > $datos/filesystem_$fecha.log &
sudo $scripts/cpu.py > $datos/cpu_$fecha.log &
```

and when i run the script I get the following error

```
./get-data.sh: line 8: /root/zabbixdata/filesystem_2020_01_02.log: Permission denied
./get-data.sh: line 9: /root/zabbixdata/cpu_2020_01_02.log: Permission denied
```

The permissions of the python scripts:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser myuser 1629 Jan  2 12:01 cpu.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser myuser 1680 Jan  2 11:06 filesystem.py
```

the permission of the bash script:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser myuser   326 Jan  2 11:51 get-data.sh
```

the permission of the target directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 6 Jan  2 11:43 zabbixdata
```

the persmission of the scripts directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 93 Jan  2 12:14 scripts
```

It seem that I have all the permission but still I can create those file via shell scripting

any ideas?

Comment: Do you run your script as `myuser `?

Comment: yes, I dont have the root user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the permission of your /root directory are 0550 (the default in a Centos server).

```
# stat /root/
File: /root/
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 10747905    Links: 23
Access: (0550/dr-xr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

If you execute the script "get-data.sh" with the user myuser, the standard output redirection  is performed by your shell which does not have the permission to access to /root. The redirection of the output is not performed by sudo.

There is a missing 'x' flag in 'other' section of /root permission that allows to access to the subdirectories /root/zabbixdata/ but maybe you don't want add it for security reasons.
In [1] you can find some example of use of redirection with sudo.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr